# Do we need a liberalism tag

Tags: discussion

I just saw we have a liberalism tag.

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liberalism

Do we really need this? It does not seem to be on-topic for the site.

If we agree that we don't need it, can someone with mod priviliges delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should remove the tag because

1) The word "liberal", "liberalism" may indeed be used in economic *contexts*, but alone and on its own, it is mostly perceived as describing something in politics rather than in economics.

2) Even if one argues that the users here will "read" the tag in an economic context, the problem then is to clearly define "liberalism" from an economic point of view. (is it, say, "laissez passer laissez faire"? If yes the latter is our own tag. Is it something else?)

3) Even if we want the tag as a political tag because "economics in real life is intertwined with politics", as a political label also liberalism is too liberal a label, it definitely defies a world-wide definition (as most political labels do).

Answer (score 5):

We should remove the tag, it is about politics, not economics.

Comment: We don't have a lot of questions with the tag and it though it could be useful descriptively, it might encourage a lot of questions out of the scope of the site. I have no problem getting rid of it.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry I have just realized that [one of the tagged questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/sens-liberal-paradox) is from you. Always the troublemaker :) I'll wait a few more days before accepting the most upvoted answer.

Comment: It was from my more frivolous years I suppose xd if you don't like it fight me! But yeah in theory it can be a good tag but in practice it hasnt really gotten much use. We'll see what some of the others say.

Comment: And also "liberal" in politics means something different in the UK than in the US: see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/32qbkt/eli5_the_difference_between_american_liberal_and/).

Answer (score 3):

We should keep the tag, it is sometimes necessary to intertwine political and economic philosophies.

Comment: I upvoted to keep it, not because I'm a fan of liberalism, but because I agree that it sometimes impossible to separate economics from politics. Especially when it comes to policy recommendations or political economy the two often go together, no matter how positivist  & neutral we try to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a relevant tag for economics. Irrespective of the way the tag has been applied to any question, the fact remains that liberalism is an economic context. That fact that it is used usually in a political context (perhaps social liberalism(??) at least in USA as far as I know) that inverts its true (original) meaning in economics, does not mean that liberalism gets removed from the domain of economics.

Perhaps, it would be correct, if questions where liberalism is used as a tag to refer to/imply the (current) political use of the term are edited so that the tag is not used incorrectly (in the economic sense).